# Comparisson between date() and a date from wp_postmeta

Tags: plugins, wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

I am using the calendar plugin: "The Events Calendar", and is trying to get the events that are done. I can't see what it is that I'm doing wrong, but I'm pretty sure that my meta_query is wrong, somewhere.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d") . " 00:00:00";
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'tribe_events',
    'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
    'meta_key'          => '_EventStartDate',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_EventStartDate',
            'value'     => $today,
            'compare'   => '<',
            'type'      => 'CHAR',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'start-date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);
echo $today;
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The date echoed is 2014-11-20 00:00:00, the date in the database says 2014-11-19 08:00:00.

If I change the parameter to anything but >, >= or != I'm not getting any posts. But if I use one of these parameters I get what I would expect from that parameter.

Link to the testing page: http://beta.musalaha.org/participants/

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meta_query arguments, try changing your

```
 'type'      => 'CHAR',
```

to

```
 'type'      => 'DATETIME',
```

You can opt for any one of these, depending your needs:

> type (string) - Custom field type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC',
>   'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME',
>   'UNSIGNED'. Default value is 'CHAR'.

**But wait! There's more! ;)**

It seems that The Events Calendar hooks into queries that involve `'post_type' => 'tribe_events'`!

You'll need to add either

```
'eventDisplay' => 'past',
```

or

```
'eventDisplay' => 'all',
```

to your arguments.

..or, you can also go with

```
$my_past_events = tribe_get_events(
    array(
        'posts_per_page'=>999,
        'eventDisplay'=>'past',
    )
);
```

and loop through $my_past_events.